# correcting unhashable type: 'dict_keys'

Tags: python, python-3.x

try to find the max value in a nested dictionary, but showed unhashable type: 'dict_keys'error

Suppose I have this dictionary:

```
d = {'A': {'a':2, 'b':2, 'c':0},
     'B': {'a':2, 'b':0, 'c':1}}
```

I want the code to return all the key(s) that contain maximum values within the dictionary (i.e. the maximum value in dictionary A is 2, and I want the code to return me the corresponding keys: 'a' and 'b')

```
['a','b']
```

here is the code I wrote:

```
max_value = max(d[Capital_Alph].values()))
return [key for key, value in d[Capital_Alph].items()
        if value == max_value]
```

Comment: `return` only makes sense in functions. You code does not. Please fix your code so it is a complete [mcve].

Comment: values of your dictionary are dictionaries. it makes no sense to compare them

Comment: `max(d[Capital_Alph].values()))` has two opening parentheses, but three closing ones -> heed [Patrick Artners's prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54392320/#comment95596437_54392320), if not [good general advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

So you have a dictionary with a str as value and a dict as key, You can do something like this:

```
d = {'A': {'a':2, 'b':2, 'c':0},
     'B': {'a':2, 'b':0, 'c':1}}
print(list(d['A'].keys()))
```

Returns:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Is this a viable solution to what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you for your response, but actually I want the code to return all the keys that contains maximum value (i.e. I want the code to return 'a' and 'b' for dictionary A since 2 is the maximum value in A)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use non-hashable datatypes as keys for sets or dict. You can accomplish your task by:

```
d = {'A': {'a':2, 'b':2, 'c':0},
     'B': {'a':2, 'b':0, 'c':1}}

max_v = {k:max(d[k].values()) for k in d }   # get the max value of the inner dict
print(max_v)

for inner in max_v:
    print("Max keys of dict {} are: {}".format(inner, 
          [k for k,v in d[inner].items() if v == max_v[inner]]))
```

Output:

```
{'A': 2, 'B': 2} # max values of inner dicts

Max keys of dict A are: ['a', 'b']
Max keys of dict B are: ['a']
```

The part `[k for k,v in d[inner].items() if v == max_v[inner]]))` is needed to get all inner keys (if multiple exists) that have the same maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code: there are too many `)` characters in your calculation of `max_value` and you can't use `return` outside a function.

But if I fix those issues and do this:

```
>>> d = {'A': {'a':2, 'b':2, 'c':0},
         'B': {'a':2, 'b':0, 'c':1}}
>>> Capital_Alph = "A" 
>>> max_value = max(d[Capital_Alph].values())
>>> [key for key, value in d[Capital_Alph].items()
         if value == max_value]
['a', 'b']
```

it's clear that there isn't a lot else wrong here. To avoid complicating things I didn't put the obvious loop around this:

```
for Capital_Alph in d:
```

but you can manage that on your own. Your error message is because you tried to make `Capital_Alph` a `dict_keys` object, in other words `d.keys()`, and use that as a key. You can't do that. You have to step through the list of dictionary keys yourself.